# como evitar excepciones en firebird

Tags: firebird

planteo mi problema, necesito si es posible atrapar una excepcion y evitar que revierta o cancele mi insercion o update para que los datos locales se guarden si o si.

Cuando inserto un registro en la tabla1 tengo que disparar por medio de un trigger un procedimiento para insertarlo en otras bases de datos, pero si alguna de estas inserciones en el procedimiento falla no quiero que se revierta mi insercion en la tabla1, sino que guarde la sentencia sql de las bases de datos que fallaron para poder ejecutarlas posteriormente.

no tengo idea si esto es posible y no encuentro las palabras correctas para encontrarlo.

```
on insert trigger
try
    procedimiento de insercion en base externa
on exception
    insertar en tabla para ejecutar mas tarde
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

voy a contestar mi propia pregunta, luego de insistir y releer varias veces los mismos resultados de la busqueda encontre esta solucion 
http://www.janus-software.com/fbmanual/manual.php?book=psql&topic=24